# ASP.NET Wepapplication with on-disk database - how?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, localdb

How can I use an .mdf file (called SQL Server Database in VS2012) for Entity Framework?

I get this error message:

`Invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename'.`

This is my connectionstring:

`<add name="DbContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Database.Db.csdl|res://*/Database.Db.ssdl|res://*/Database.Db.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;initial catalog=DataContext;Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataContext.mdf;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`.

In Global.asax.cs, Application_Start I set the correct path for `|DataDirectory|` like this:

`string newPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_Data");`

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", newPath);`

Do any of you know to make this work?

Btw. it works when running my web application locally (i.e. debug), and does not work when publishing to my online domain.

Comment: What would the path to the directory be on your online domain? Does it accept "\"? Have you tried testing with the full path specified?

Comment: It would be something like: `D:\home\krbak\[projectname]\App_Data`. I have tried with this path specified in the connectionstring.

If I browse my connection to the MDF via the Server Browser, and right-click, select "Manage Connection", I see an absolute path to the MDF file, and not a relative one.

Answer (score 0):

If it works locally but not online, the problem is from `data source` part of your connection string. And if you want to attach your db at runtime, not by management studio, remove the `initial catalig` part. So change it to something like the following:

```
<add name="DbContainer" 
  connectionString="metadata=res://*/Database.Db.csdl|res://*/Database.Db.ssdl
  |res://*/Database.Db.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
  provider connection string=&quot;data source=RemoteServerInstance;      
  Integrated Security=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataContext.mdf;
  MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```